# System architecture for vessel management system

Tags: architecture, cassandra, real-time, distributed

I was wondering if anyone could give me some thoughts on how to best design a vessel management system with the following requirements;

1. The system onboard the vessel gathers sensor data.
2. The system on the vessel is mostly connected to the internet, but sometimes days without.
3. Users need to gain access/view these data both on the vessel and onshore.
4. Users onshore will also provide some input to the system that needs to be access on the vessel.

Due to having both onshore and offshore users able to access the system when vessel is "disconnected" I have started looking into Cassandra and using the synchronization features there to keep the servers onshore and offshore synched. However, Cassandra seems to me like a bit of an over-kill for this as the amount of sensor data is not massive.

Are there any easier ways of achieving this "appear always online" and constant availability and at the same time keep both servers/databases synched?

[Design example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXeOh.png)